# How dose the useEffect and useState hook works?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I am learning React Hooks I know useEffect when used without any dependency array should run after every render but what about render itself does it happen every time a state changes because I am trying following code where I am rending a static h1 to the DOM and in my useEffect I am using a fetch to call a json file on the success of the fetch I am setting a state loaded to true from false I have written this example for the learning purpose only I was expecting that this should have caused a infinite loop because useEffect without dependency array should run after every render and I am calling set state which according to me should force the render to happen but It only run the useEffect twice but
when I am using the other example where I am using useState create a name state and in the useeffect without dependency arry I am changing the name state with Math.random it is behaving as expected causing infinite loop what I understand is useState does not cause render state to happen untill the value of the state changed as in the first example the state value only changed once from false to true and in name example it is random so changes every time
Just need a to know is my understanding correct and also if you can share where I can learn these Kind of stuff as I did not find this on the react doc.

example 1 with fetch
`

```
const App = () => {
    // const [name, setName] = useState('sumit');
    const [loaded, setLoaded] =useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('sumit');
        fetch('./option.json').then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
           return res.json();
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            setLoaded(true);
        }) 
        // setName(Math.random());
    })
    return (
            <h1>sumit</h1>
    );
}
```

`example 2 with name`

```
const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('sumit');
    // const [loaded, setLoaded] =useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('sumit');
       /*  fetch('./option.json').then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
           return res.json();
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            setLoaded(true);
        }) */
        // setcount(count+1); 
        setName(Math.random());
    })
    return (
            <h1>sumit</h1>
    );
}
```

`

Comment: React will only re-render when the state actually changes, as your example shows. When your loaded state becomes `true`, setting it to true multiple times will not cause multiple renders - you wouldn't want it to. Also, some punctuation would make it much easier to read your question.

Comment: Thanks for confirming also sorry for bad punctuation. I have got one more question as I tried same code but instead of setting the state as true or false I am setting state as the response what I am getting is empty array[] every time, although The response is same it is still causing infinite loop. Does it not check for object's.

Comment: Two objects or arrays are not "equal" by default. Meaning `[] !== []` and `{} !== {}`. In those two examples, you are comparing two different objects (two different locations in memory), so they're not the same thing. What you really want here is not to compare the response from your API, but to prevent the API request in the first place. You need to pass a second parameter to `useEffect` to prevent it from running multiple times.